# Jetpack compose TextField IP address visual transformation and validation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

What is the simplest way to create a TextField in Jetpack Compose with IP address validation and Visual transformation?
I need a TextField that advances automatically to the next group of numbers in the IP address when the entered number is >25 and adds the "." automatically between each group, etc.

I've done this in XML with Constraint Layouts and 5 different TextField, one for each group of numbers in the IP plus the Port and a lot of code.

EDIT:
Checkout the gist with my IPEditText
https://gist.github.com/SerggioC/0de52b67341ea523bfc49c027a270ed7
Put the custom view in a XML layout to see how it works.

Comment: can u share the view you made with xml and you want to do with jetpack compose?

Comment: Please share input examples for IP addresses you want to cover in VisualTransformation. That would help answer the question.

Comment: @commandiron check out the edited message.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the same View you defined in XML within Compose

```
AndroidView(
  factory = { context ->
    IPEEdittext(...)
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, might use this initially, but my idea is to use compose and simplify this long IPEditText class.